# How to disable "detect_unicode" setting from php.ini? (trying to install Composer)

Tags: php, composer-php

I've been trying to install Composer on my machine (OS X 10.6) with no success so far.

As per Composer docs, i executed this in Terminal:

> curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php#!/usr/bin/env php

And this is the output:

> The detect_unicode setting must be disabled. Add the following to the
>   end of your `php.ini`:
>       detect_unicode = Off

Of course, this is in my php.ini: detect_unicode = Off, located at /etc/php.ini.default

php -info tells me that php.ini file is being loaded from /etc/ (output is: Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc)

But, also outputs: detect_unicode => On => On

Why php.ini.default is not loading my settings and how could i disable effecively detect_unicode?

Comment: You need to restart php for changes to take effect.

Comment: I did restart once or twice... is there a way to restart php?

Comment: A reboot kills all processes. It may be going to sleep. Try turning it off.

Comment: By unplugging it while it is on (not recommended as too much can break the comp), plugging it back in, then turning it on and checking php.ini

Comment: Then this sounds like a bug with composer. It sounds like it just scans the ink file for it being on whether it is commented or not. :/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Most likely *no* ini file at all is being loaded, I don't know if /etc/php.ini.default is seen or not by php. Same as I said in [Can't set/find detect_unicode to Off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241568/cant-set-find-detect-unicode-to-off) - you should run `php -i | grep ini` and check which file actually is loaded, then edit it. If none is loaded, then make sure you put a php.ini file into the `Configuration File Path` value, in your case `/etc/php.ini` it seems.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "put a php.ini file into the Configuration File Path value" please? I have the same problem as above. I have tried to edit my php.ini file but no success. It must be being loaded because I have altered other aspects of it that have come into effect.

Comment: @Seldaek I ended up doing: curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php -d detect_unicode=Off
to override the detect_unicode check.
But thanks anyhow.

Comment: @musoNic80 - What I meant is that if there is no file in that path then you can create one. As for the workaround, you can also do `curl ... | php -- --force` to bypass all checks

Comment: Thanks @Seldaek. I didn't realise the the cl used a different php.ini than my local web server!

Answer (score 59):

Just add "-d detect_unicode=Off" after the command

```
curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -d detect_unicode=Off
```

Comment: This answer should be at the top!

Answer (score 18):

Under OSX go to `/etc`.

Open Terminal.

```
>cd /etc
>nano php.ini.default
```

Edit the `php.ini.default` (insert `detect_unicode = Off`).

Save the file.

Now rename it to `php.ini`.

```
>mv /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini
```

Restart Terminal and then it should work proberly.

Comment: *Copy* the default `cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini`, then edit the copy. That way if you make a bad edit it's easy to get the original back.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't change your /usr/local/bin/php/php.ini file, remember to keep using '-d detect_unicode=Off' for all your php calls like so:

```
curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -d detect_unicode=Off

php -d detect_unicode=Off composer.phar install
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few solutions online, but the easiest I found was on Stack Overflow. The problem is that the PHP CLI doesn’t load the same php.ini by default, and unlike on most Linux installations there isn’t a seperate php-cli.ini and seemingly /etc/php.ini.default doesn’t load so much. You can pass it as a runtime parameter though:

```
curl -s getcomposer.org/installer | php -d detect_unicode=Off
```

source -> http://www.andrew-kirkpatrick.com/2012/10/install-composer-for-php-on-zend-server-mac-os-x/